# Set focus to element after slideToggle removes display:hidden attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, focus

So I have looked at a bunch of examples and still cannot seem to figure this one out. I have an element that I am hiding "display:none" until it is expanded by a link using jQuery slideToggle. Working but I need the focus to go to the new element div. I've tried a bunch of examples and nothing seems to be working so I'll post it here.

Here is the fiddle:
[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E85pn/6/)

So on click of this link here:

```
<div><p>Blah Blah <a id="whyDivLink" class="staticLinkHelper" title="Wblah blah bl title" style="color: #8f0222; text-decoration: underline">Click Me?</a></p>
</div>
```

I am trying to do two things, well three but two would be marvelous.
1. Scroll to this DIV which is just a bit further down the page.
2. Focus on the text that is now showing.

Apparently because the node is hidden, then it will not focus to it or something to that affect and it has nothing to scrollTo or when I have tried it just scrolls all the way to the top. But I have a fixed header so that does not work because then it is just hidden. So what I have now is basically working and scrolling to the div and from what I can tell... focusing on it. But I need to set it a ways from the top and when I try it breaks the scrolling. Any one see what I am doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
$("#whyDivCloser").click(function () {
    $("#whyDiv").slideToggle("slow");
});
});

$(function() {
$('#whyDivLink').click(function (evt) {
    $("#whyDiv").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like when you apply `display:none` ***initially*** to the `div`, clicking on the `a` link won't lead user to the targeted `div` anymore. To fix this, you can try using code to hide the `div` initially using `slideToggle`, of course the initial state of the `div` is `display:block`, `slideToggle` will hide it for you instead of setting `display:none` initially while clicking on the link will work expectedly (jump to the targeted `div`).

**JS**:

```
$(function() {
  $("#whyDiv").slideToggle("slow"); //add this line to hide it initially
  $("#whyDivCloser").click(function () {
    $("#whyDiv").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

$(function() {
$('#whyDivLink').click(function (evt) {        
         //append .focus() to focus the text
         $("#whyDiv").slideToggle("slow").focus();  
    });
});
```

### [Updated Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/E85pn/7/)

Comment: You actually answered it because you're just that good. :) I added display:block and it works. Will have to see why but for now it's working in FF, Chrome and Safari. Will have to test IE later. Thanks King! http://jsfiddle.net/E85pn/9/